# Movement after already having used the script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple 2D game in unity and I am trying to "animate" the buttons and title to split out when you press the reset button I have made.  I am using the same script at the beginning when the player starts the game. Anyone know what that could be wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoBuOOF : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float move = 0.03f;
    private float time = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame

    private void Start()
    {
        time = 0;
        move = 0.03f;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime;

        if (1.5 < time)
        {
            if (0.12f > move)
            {

                transform.Translate(Vector2.down * move);
                move += 0.001f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the MonoBehaviour script. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: We don't know what could be wrong, because you don't say. What happens and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I use this script to move the buttons out of frame when the game first start. Then when you press the button again after collision the buttons should move out of frame but they just stay at the same position

Comment: `Then when you press the button again after collision the buttons should move` .. where is he code for that?  Currently things are coded to happen each `FixedUpdate` call as long as `1.5 < time` and `0.12f > move` ... `time` and `move` never get reset so the object will never move again (at least not via this component)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.